# is intel icpc openmp slower than icc openmp

Tags: openmp, intel, icc

I am doing a 3D simulation of a diffusion-reaction model using finite difference. The system has over 8 million nodes in size. To solve the problem, both icc + openmp and icpc + openmp have been used. As a result, the icc + openmp turns out to be as 3-fold faster than that of icpc-openmp. The huge difference in computational time is confusing. So I am asking if icpc-openmp is actually slower than icc-openmp.
For more information:

1. intel compiler version: 15.0.1 20141023
2. all reaction equations were solved using c functions (not class objects).
3. Makefile options:

   a) icc+openmp:

   ```
   CC = icc
   CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Ilib -O3 -openmp
   LDFLAGS= -lz 
   Main: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard lib/*.c))
   ```

   b) icpc+openmp:

   ```
   CXX=icpc  
   CFLAGS = -Wall -Ilib -O3 -openmp -std=c++11  
   CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Ilib -O3 -openmp -std=c++11 
   LDFLAGS= -lz
   main: $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard lib/*.cpp))
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: Add -std=c99 just to be sure you're enforcing some language spec in the C case.

Comment: There should be no difference between icc and icpc as they are only different drivers ending up at the same compiler at the end. Do you have profiling data so that we can see where the additional run time was spend? If possible can you share the sources? I would be interested to investigate in this.

Comment: @Jeff, adding the -std=c99 flag gives:    icpc: command line warning #10381: option '-std=c99' is not valid for C++ compilations

Comment: Then it's not a C program and you should not use icc to compile it. And to be clear, I meant use that option with icc, not icpc.

Comment: Problem is likely too specific to user. And is 2 years old.